# NSData from Shorted URL not make UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata, url-shortener

I am facing problem with downloading a .jpg image using a shorted URL like this one:

shorted URL:-  https://db.tt/KH5NgfT1

I got successfully `NSData` length of 41791 bytes. But problem is when I convert this NSData to UIImage it gives NULL and when this NULL image I am posting on faceBook It successfully posted to my facebook account, for post on facebook I am using `SLComposeViewController` and one thing more that is this Image is also not shown in `SLComposeViewController`.

I am using this code for download image

```
NSData *downloadedImageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:shortedURL]];
```

Convert to UIImage

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:downloadedImageData];
```

returns NULL image

and My `SLComposeViewController` look like this

[My SLComposeViewController screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5443wq99wu9a0bu/IMG_3679.PNG)

I want to show downloaded image in SLComposeViewController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO erkanyildiz maybe your above answer is wrong because there is no difference between long and shorted URL they both redirect me to a image once look at this

1. this shorted url not works because it's from DropBox

   ```
   NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://db.tt/KH5NgfT1"] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
   UIImage *downloadedImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
   ```
2. this shorted url works because it's NOT from DropBox

   ```
   NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://goo.gl/FTh7No"] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
   UIImage *downloadedImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
   ```
3. this long url not works because it's from DropBox

   ```
   NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/5443wq99wu9a0bu/IMG_3679.PNG"] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
   UIImage *downloadedImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
   ```
4. this long url works because it's NOT from DropBox

   ```
   NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/20130627-DROPBOX-OFFICE-147edit.jpg"] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
   UIImage *downloadedImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
   ```

So, finally I think the problem is at DropBox server may be they have some kind of web-encription so that we can't download image directly using    NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
and may be because of web-encription it support to Facebook.

solution is DropBox provides api for downloading image 
https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files//

[DropBox Core API Documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs)

Thanks for Replying

Answer (score 3):

That shortened URL is not redirecting you to an image file as it is hotlink protected. It redirects you to a simple HTML page where you can see the image. So, `NSData` you get using `dataWithContentsOfURL` is not an image file data, and `imageWithData` method returns nil as expected.

And you say it is displayed correctly on Facebook when you post it, then it looks like Facebook handles this Dropbox image hotlink protection itself to get the image directly.

You might need to do the same trick by yourself.

For example, direct hotlink to your image is: https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/0/AAAZy24NIIDzdh-J7L2fei34nM1AMnuBbLcV-nc2VAvpTg/12/105579065/jpeg/1024x768/3/1383656400/0/2/04-11-2013_16-53-16.jpg/ooh2MQDiN0DOjsEiwM68rI2buAyfTtbfog-UzrmvMqw